# How do I dynamically include a PHP script?

Tags: php, security

I'm writing code in PHP that requires including a `config.php` file depending on the website URL.

I've the website URL in the variable `$site`, and the config for `$site` is in the directory `configs/$site/config.php`.

How can I require this file dynamically in PHP?

Is it safe to do `include "configs/$site/config.php";`?

Comment: You say "require" but then you demonstrate `include `...?

Comment: True, you might want to use `require "configs/$site/config.php";`

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos - In this case, with a `config` file, `require_once` probably is the most useful approach.

Comment: @JaredFarrish completely true

Comment: Thanks for comments. I don't know the difference between `include` and `require` yet. I'll read up on them right now. (I've been using them interchangeably until now.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you limit `$site` to a set of values, yes.

```
$sites = array(
  'siteA',
  'siteB'
);
if (isset($sites[$site])) {
  include "configs/$site/config.php";
} else {
  throw new Exception("Unknown site");
}
```

But remember: *Never* trust anything from outside, *always* validate values, that come from a client (browser).

Comment: Never trust. Always validate. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

That is fine. Just make sure the `$site` variable cannot be changed by the user! If the user can change it, he can make it include any file.

Comment: `$site` depends on the `Host` header, thanks for reminding me that user can include any file if he sets `Host` to `../../file\0` or something similar!